# Como grabar un archivo de Excel que se genera de SAP

Tags: python, excel, sap

Cuando se ejecuta la transacción IW22 en SAP, se genera un archivo de "Hoja de Calculo de Basis"
[image: Ver imagen de la hoja de calculo] , necesito grabar esa hoja como un archivo de excel por medio de comandos de python.
Ya he probado con Pandas, openpyxl, pero la ayuda inicia creando un objeto nuevo con el métdo Workbook, pero no se como direccionarlo hacia el archivo del a "Hoja de Cálculo de Basis", la cual busco en mi PC y es un archivo temporal que desaparece al cerrar SAP.

Mil gracias...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mi falla es que necesito grabar un archivo de excel que genera SAP cuando ejecuto la transacción IW29, el archivo es un .tmp y se debe de grabar con extensión de excel. Esto se hace facilmente de forma manual, usando la ventana de grabar como. Pero mi necesidad es hacerlo con comandos de Python, pero no me funciona, esa es la ayuda que necesito.